# SQL Server - why the foreign keys aren't connecting to the primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, inner-join

I want to insert the primary keys to all their foreign keys. I changed my procedure and still get nulls or empty rows:

[image: dbo.Stories - null]
[[image: here are the tables][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwjbN.png)

The other connected tables are all empty.

My procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertText    
    @UserID [INT],
    @story [NVARCHAR](120),
    @img [VARCHAR](MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Stories ([StoryText]) 
    VALUES (@story)

    INSERT INTO Images ([img]) 
    VALUES (@img)

    SELECT        
        dbo.Table_Users.UserID , dbo.Stories.StoryID, dbo.Images.imgID
    FROM            
        dbo.Images 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.imagesInStories ON dbo.Images.imgID = dbo.imagesInStories.imgID3   
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.Stories ON dbo.Images.imgID = dbo.Stories.imgID2 
                    AND dbo.imagesInStories.StoryID3 = dbo.Stories.StoryID 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.Users_Stories ON dbo.Stories.StoryID = dbo.Users_Stories.StoryID2 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.Table_Users ON dbo.Users_Stories.ID2 = dbo.Table_Users.UserID
    WHERE 
        dbo.Table_Users.UserID = @UserID
END
GO

-- exec UserStory 3, 'today nothing worked ???', 'meyesterday.jpg'
```

I hope you understand.

Can't find any answer anywhere

And tried for days.

Comment: Show us the **table structures** - what do these tables look like?

Comment: You create a new row in `dbo.Stories`, only populate `StoryText`, and are wondering why `ImgID2` is null?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Here's a good starting place: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @marc_s Hi, I added the tables screen shots

Comment: @PaulAbbott what are you saying ? I don't understand at all. I can make insert to []  values by hand. but  with proc I can't.

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting two single values in two different tables, but your query seems to show that you need more information to "connect" the inserted values. The inserted *Story* will receive a `StoryID` and the *Image* receives an `imgID`. Supposed that your query is correct, you will have to change your code as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertText    
    @UserID [INT],
    @story [NVARCHAR](120),
    @img [VARCHAR](MAX)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @StoryID int, @ImageID int;

    INSERT INTO dbo.Images ([img]) 
    VALUES (@img);

    SET @ImageID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    INSERT INTO dbo.Stories ([StoryText], imgID2) 
    VALUES (@story, @ImageID);

    SET @StoryID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    INSERT INTO dbo.imagesInStories (StoryID3, imgID3)
    VALUES (@StoryID, @ImageID);

    INSERT INTO dbo.Users_Stories (ID2, StoryID2)
    VALUES (@UserID, @StoryID);

    SELECT  Table_Users.UserID , Stories.StoryID, Images.imgID
    FROM  dbo.Images 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.imagesInStories ON Images.imgID = imagesInStories.imgID3   
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.Stories ON Images.imgID = Stories.imgID2 
                    AND imagesInStories.StoryID3 = Stories.StoryID 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.Users_Stories ON Stories.StoryID = Users_Stories.StoryID2 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.Table_Users ON Users_Stories.ID2 = Table_Users.UserID
    WHERE 
        Table_Users.UserID = @UserID
END
```

You should maybe re-design your table structure: the stories and images seem to be linkd in two ways: 1:n directly and m:n via table `imagesInStories`.

**Added:**

I declared the variables `@StoryID` and `@ImageID` to store the values of the identity column of both tables right after a new record is inserted using the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` system function. The new `@ImageID` is needed when inserting the *Story* that the *Image* belongs to, and the new `@StoryID` is needed when adding an image-story-connection (to the `imagesInStories` table) and when adding the new story to the stories of the user (table `Users_Stories`).

Your original query joins *Images* and *Stories* in two ways:

1. using the `imgID2` column in the `Stories` table
2. using both `imgID3` and `StoryID3` column in the `imagesInStories` table.

I think that one way to connect images and stories is enough, that's why I was talking about re-design. Does each *Story* have at most one *Image*? If so, remove the table `imagesInStories`, and if not, remove the `imgID2` column from the `Stories` table. However, your query uses both ways, which will return incomplete results when there are multiple images linked to a story, because the query will only return the one image who's ID is saved in the `imgID2`column of the `Stories` table.

Comment: Thank you, did you looked at my tables screenshot above  at my question ? becasue I have already StroryID and imgID, so I don't understand how can I declar them.

Comment: If I had more than 2 IDs colums at dbo.images how will  the scope_identity() function knows exactly what last identity to return ? For another example if in dbo.Stories I had  3 primary keys which (4 colums overall)   which the SET @someID = SCOPE_IDENTITY() know to choose from ?

Comment: The `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` returns the value of the most recently changed `identity` column, and there can be only one such column per table (look at your tables screenshot).

Answer (score 0):

**I deleted all this part from the code and it did worked perfectly the same !!**

```
 SELECT  Table_Users.UserID , Stories.StoryID, Images.imgID
FROM  dbo.Images 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.imagesInStories ON Images.imgID = imagesInStories.imgID3   
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Stories ON Images.imgID = Stories.imgID2 
                AND imagesInStories.StoryID3 = Stories.StoryID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Users_Stories ON Stories.StoryID = Users_Stories.StoryID2 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Table_Users ON Users_Stories.ID2 = Table_Users.UserID
WHERE 
    Table_Users.UserID = @UserID
```

***was it necessary?*** 
**P.S** 
What did you mean by:" You should maybe re-design your table structure: the stories and images seem to be linkd in two ways: 1:n directly and m:n via table imagesInStories"  - I don't understand, can you please explain me?

I'm just so new in this SQL.
Thanks for the answers

Comment: I just added more explanation to my answer.

Comment: Whether the select statement is neccessary or not depends on what is expected by the application the uses the procedure. Just for adding the desired records to the respective tables, it is of course not neccessary. But, of course somewhere in the application, a query like this has to be used… see my concerns in my amended answer.

Comment: @Wolfgand Kais Hi, how can I receive few images with the story together from Stories table, when I’ll add another proc which add one picture at a time or many at once? I asked my lecturer, she said the tables are all fine, but you seems to be the knowledgeable here. Can you please give me an advice how to write the tables as right? So I can receive as asked?

Comment: So you want to be able to assign more than one *Image* to a *Story*? Then the field `Stories.imgID2` is useless. To add more *Images* to an existant *Story*, you will need another stored procedure that accepts a `@StoryID int` and a `@img varchar(max)` parameter.

Comment: The question is: What is the meaning of that *Image* that is directly assigned to a *Story* and what is the meaning of the multiple *Images* that can also be assigned to (one or more) *Stories*. And which of those you are trying to insert using your procedure. I think you will have to ask your lecturer.

Comment: @WolfgangKais O.K thanks, now I want in one procedure to insert one or more images with the story to the database, any idea how to do so? (I thought to use - if  @@ROWCOUNT>0  if there is more than one image or images at all). I'll later create  procedure which get the story (nvarchar) with all the images.

Comment: How will you tell the procedure the more than one images to add? `@@ROWCOUNT` of what? I suggest to ask a new question for that. But first: Ask your lecturer.

Comment: @WolfgangKais  Lecturer is on vacation, I'm supposed to learn by myself. good night

Comment: Well, ok, then it isn't urgent, I guess, … Maybe you can amend your original post one of these days and say a little bit more about the purpose of the database, especially about the "Stories" and the "Images" (and their number) connected to them. Sleep well! :-)